# Swift Array of class : how to find index in a method of the class

Tags: arrays, class, swift, methods, indexing

Let's consider the following code :

```
Class AClass : SKNode
{
    func AFunction ()
    {
        // Some code
    }
}

var AnArrayOfAClass[AClass]()

AnArrayOfAClass[x].AFunction
```

How can I know in AFunction the value of the index when I call the method AFunction (index is x in the example of call I want to do like in the last line of code just above) ? Is there a way to avoid to pass it as an argument of AFunction ?

Thx

J.

Comment: What is the scope of `AnArrayOfAClass`?

Comment: What do you mean by scope (I'm kind of new to swift) ?

Comment: No worries :) I meant where is it being used in relation to the instance of AClass that is calling it? A function or a closure can "capture" values outside of themselves, but only other values that are in the same "scope" as the function. Sorry, I don't know how to describe it better in a comment, but I don't think it is possible to answer without knowing the scope in which the array and the function are being called...

Comment: The     ‘AnArrayOfAClass‘ array is a global variable declared outside of any specific scope (i.e. not in a function or class) and used at various levels in the code. The     'AFunction' method is called inside the didBeginContact of a SKScene object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this will work because I'm still not certain of the scope issue, but this will return the index of the first value in `AnArrayOfAClass` that is identical to the object calling the function:

```
class AClass {
    func aFunction() {

        //  This maps AnArrayOfAClass to an array of Bool values depending
        //  on whether or not the value at the index === the object calling the function
        //  and then returns the index of the first true that it encounters:

        if let index = find(anArrayOfAClass.map({ $0 === self }), true) {
            println(index)
        }
    }
}

var anArrayOfAClass = [AClass]()

let aClass = AClass()

anArrayOfAClass += [aClass]

anArrayOfAClass[0].aFunction()   //  If everything worked, this should print "0", 
                                 //  which is the correct index of aClass
```

And I changed everything to camelCase where I thought it was appropriate - no offense intended :)

Comment: And if you make AClass conform to Equatable, you can use `find` directly without having to do the map first.

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks ! I just have now to figure out why and how it works...I'll go back to Swift 101 for that...;-)